# Can we use an android library (aar) in a GeneXus android app?

Tags: android, genexus, android-developer-api

We have an android library for mobile data gathering (location, mobile device, etc.) that I would like to share with a partner. This aar component was developed using java and android studio, vanilla stuff.
Problem is, this partner is using GeneXus platform. I have performed a research and what I have found is that you can create an android component using GeneXus, but nothing related to consuming one (an external aar file).

Does anyone know if that is possible?

I also have verified that you can have access to "some" device data, like geo localisation, but that is it. Point is, I could create something in GeneXus, however with far less data richness than native android.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can extend Genexus Android native app by using any native library you need to use. 
Genexus provide [Extensions Library](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?33546,Creating%20an%20Extension%20Library%20for%20Android) for extensibility in native application.
You can create an [External Object](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?17878,External%20Object%20for%20Android) in Genexus and then use it in your application.

You can find a [full sample](https://github.com/genexuslabs/SDExtensionsSample) in Github with step by step documentation:

https://github.com/genexuslabs/SDExtensionsSample

Best,

Comment: Thank you @fpanizza. My Question lacked clarification, apologies for that. I don't want to share an GeneXus component, instead we got a vanilla android java aar component and would like to use it on a GeneXus project. Is that possible? Thanks again